# Can a XAML event like SizeChanged be added to a style easily, without use of an EventTrigger in the style?

Tags: xaml, events, xamarin, styles

Can a XAML event like SizeChanged be added to a style easily, without use of an EventTrigger in the style?

...

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
       <Setter Event="SizeChanged" Value="Handle_SizeChanged" /> //hoping for something like this line
    </Style>
```

...

```
<Label Text="0" SizeChanged="Handle_SizeChanged" ... //can remove SizeChanged
<Label Text="1" SizeChanged="Handle_SizeChanged" ...
<Label Text="2" SizeChanged="Handle_SizeChanged" ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an attached behavior, then include this attached behavior in your style. The behavior would wire up the SizeChanged event.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/behaviors/creating/